# Proof that the basis of a sum of two vectors with the same basis is the basis of the two vectors together

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an exercise in my algebra book. I cannot prove following:

Let x and y be in a vectorspace V
and let B be the basis of the vectors:

$$ x,y_{}\in V $$
$$ \left\lbrack x\right\rbrack_B=\left\lbrack y\right\rbrack_B=\left(a_1,\ldots a_n\right) $$

Then prove this:

$$ \left\lbrack x\right\rbrack_B+\left\lbrack y\right\rbrack_B=\left\lbrack x+y\right\rbrack_B $$

What I have done:

(1)

$$ \left\lbrack x+y\right\rbrack_B=\left\lbrack a_1x_1+a_1y_1+\ldots+a_nx_n+a_ny_n\right\rbrack $$

$$ =\left\lbrack a_1\left(x_1+y_1\right)+\cdots+a_n\left(y_n+x_n\right)\right\rbrack $$

and because x and y is a vector space, the sum of two vectors in this vector space must also be a vector in this vectorspace:
$$ y+x=z\in V $$
Now to simplify (1):

$$ [x+y]_B=\left\lbrack z\right\rbrack_B=\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right) $$

Now I will simplify the other side of the equation:

$$ \left\lbrack x\right\rbrack_B+\left\lbrack y\right\rbrack_B=\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right)+\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right)=2\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right) $$

This is not the same. Where did it go wrong? Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Take $n=1$ to see the mistake. Then $x,y\in K$ are in the field. And of course, if $y=x$, we have $x+y=2x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I do see the pattern and I've done the addition with vectors to confirm it. However I am still stuck at [a_1(x_1+y_1) + ... + a_n(x_n+y_n)]_B, because x and y cannot be factorized I am not sure how to show this proof.

Comment: Did you mean that x and y will be the same no matter the n?